# Force Wordpress Plugin Contact Form 7 to send Mails with ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am working on a website to collect leads. For that I have a WordPress installation with Contact Form 7. The system I send the mails to requires ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 charset and I need German special letters. Unfortunately this not working at all.

I was setting the additional Header in CF7 by using `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1` and if I look at the Mail Header this string is in there, but all German special letters like "äöü" and the "ß" is messed up with the well known "ÃŸ" and so on.

I am totally stuck here and don't know what I can do. I looked at the Code of CF7 (I just downloaded the plugin folder and was using `grep -r -i "utf"`) to see if I can do something there about the encoding. I found this code part here in `/includes/functions.php`:

```php
function wpcf7_count_code_units( $string ) {
    static $use_mb = null;

    if ( is_null( $use_mb ) ) {
        $use_mb = function_exists( 'mb_convert_encoding' );
    }

    if ( ! $use_mb ) {
        return false;
    }

    $string = (string) $string;
    $string = str_replace( "\r\n", "\n", $string );

    $encoding = mb_detect_encoding( $string, mb_detect_order(), true );

    if ( $encoding ) {
        $string = mb_convert_encoding( $string, 'UTF-16', $encoding );
    } else {
        $string = mb_convert_encoding( $string, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8' );
    }

    $byte_count = mb_strlen( $string, '8bit' );
```

After what I read here on Stackoverflow the `mb_convert_encoding` part should help me with my problem. But my PHP skills are not high. Is there a way to solve my problem. It would be very kind if someone here could help me with this.

PS: Here is the output on my grep command. Maybe this can help too.

```
includes/formatting.php:    $text = wp_check_invalid_utf8( $text );
includes/formatting.php:    and 'UTF-8' == get_option( 'blog_charset' ) ) {
includes/formatting.php:        $text = mb_convert_kana( $text, 'asKV', 'UTF-8' );
includes/submission.php:                    $tied_item = html_entity_decode( $tied_item, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
includes/submission.php:            $value = wp_check_invalid_utf8( $value );
includes/functions.php:     $string = mb_convert_encoding( $string, 'UTF-16', $encoding );
includes/functions.php:     $string = mb_convert_encoding( $string, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8' );
modules/constant-contact.php:               'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
modules/constant-contact.php:               'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
modules/constant-contact.php:               'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Comment: "The system I send the mails to requires ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252". I apologize for questioning you on this, but are you 100% certain of this? Is there a system _beyond_ the SMTP system that cannot support Unicode? If that's the case, I can believe that. But any SMTP transport from the past decade (or two or three) should be able to handle that with MIME. Changing CF7/PHP/WordPress to act like it is the 90's is probably possible, but before we go down that path, you should be 100% certain.

Comment: Hi Chris, yes iḿ 100% sure. But its not the SMTP System. I send the mail with the data from the formular to a third party system where the Leads are stored to be selled.